# MySQL: slow query with many joins

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search

I have a database containing about 100 hundreds Mysql-tables. All tables are under INNODB.
Our company provide a grammar check and translation services to ours users.

Here is simplified database schema

[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJZpv.png)

Each user can search there own projects by keyword via a search engine. Each query uses full text search.

I also created a view:

```
create view searches as 
Select
  project_contents.content_markdown,
  project_contents.content_jp_markdown,
  project_contents.remarks_markdown,
  project_corrections.correction_markdown,
  project_corrections.comment_markdown,
  project_messages.message_from_markdown,
  project_messages.message_to_markdown,
  projects.id,
  projects.user_id,
  projects.project_category_id,
  projects.uuid,
  projects.teacher_id,
  projects.title,
  projects.is_deleted,
  projects.submit_date,
  projects.receipt_date,
  projects.correct_date,
  project_questions.question_markdown,
  project_questions.answer_markdown,
  project_rates.content_markdown As rate_content_markdown,
  teachers.username,
  project_categories.parent_id,
  project_additional_writings.append_markdown
From
  project_contents 
    INNER JOIN projects
        ON project_contents.project_id = projects.id
    INNER JOIN project_messages
        ON project_messages.project_id = projects.id 
    INNER JOIN project_categories
        ON projects.project_category_id = project_categories.id
    LEFT JOIN project_questions
        ON project_questions.project_id = projects.id 
    LEFT JOIN project_rates
        ON project_rates.project_id = projects.id
    LEFT JOIN project_corrections
        ON project_corrections.project_content_id = project_contents.id 
    LEFT JOIN project_additional_writings
        ON project_additional_writings.project_id = projects.id
    LEFT JOIN teachers
        ON projects.teacher_id = teachers.id
```

and here the query

```
SELECT   `search`.`id`,
         `search`.`uuid`,
         `search`.`user_id`,
         `search`.`parent_id`,
         `search`.`project_category_id`,
         `search`.`teacher_id`,
         `search`.`username`,
         `search`.`is_deleted`,
         `search`.`title`,
         `search`.`submit_date`,
         `search`.`receipt_date`,
         `search`.`correct_date`,
         `search`.`content_jp_markdown`,
         `search`.`remarks_markdown`,
         `search`.`content_markdown`,
         `search`.`correction_markdown`,
         `search`.`comment_markdown`,
         `search`.`question_markdown`,
         `search`.`answer_markdown`,
         `search`.`append_markdown`,
         `search`.`rate_content_markdown`,
         `search`.`message_from_markdown`,
         `search`.`message_to_markdown`,
         `search`.`memo_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`title`) against('"famous blogger"'                 IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_title`,
         (match(`search`.`content_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'      IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_content_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`content_jp_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'   IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_content_jp_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`remarks_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'      IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_remarks_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`correction_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'   IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_correction_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`comment_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'      IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_comment_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`message_from_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"' IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_message_from_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`message_to_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'   IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_message_to_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`question_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'     IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_question_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`answer_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'       IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_answer_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`append_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'       IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_append_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`rate_content_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"' IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_rate_content_markdown`,
         (match(`search`.`memo_markdown`) against('"famous blogger"'         IN boolean mode)) AS `search__score_memo_markdown`
FROM     `idiy_v3`.`searches`  AS `search`
WHERE    `search`.`is_deleted` = '0'
AND      `search`.`parent_id` = 1
AND      `search`.`user_id` = 217
AND      ((`search`.`username` LIKE '%famous blogger%')
         OR (match(`search`.`title`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`content_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`content_jp_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`remarks_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`correction_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`comment_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`message_from_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`message_to_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`question_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`answer_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`append_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`rate_content_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode))
         OR (match(`search`.`memo_markdown`) against('\"famous blogger\"' IN boolean mode)))
GROUP BY `search`.`id`
ORDER BY `search`.`submit_date` DESC limit 5
```

By default each query takes between 15 and 25 seconds (depends the number of projects by users, the keywords, etc).

When I remove the columns from `project_corrections` tables, 
the query fall under 10 seconds.

Why there is so much differences?
How can I optimize my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new table that has *copies* of the username and all the markdowns concatenated into a single `TEXT` column.  Have a `FULLTEXT` index on that column.  Your `SELECT` would do a single `MATCH` against that column, then `JOIN` to the other tables to get the details.

One `MATCH` will be about 13 times as fast as doing 13 `MATCHes`.  And `OR` is hard to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to automatically update this new table if one of the others had new records or an updating ?

Comment: I don't think a `TRIGGER` is  practical.  Write a subroutine in your application that takes care of the extra `INSERT`.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you so much :)